# Create array from url hash divided by "/" using Jquery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, hash

I have a hash in the URL that I've dynamically created using checkboxes, on the page load/document ready I'm checking to see if a hash exists and then if it does I want to loop through each string and do something with them.

for example my hash looks like these below.

```
#thing1/thing2/thing3/thing4/thing5/thing6/thing7/thing8/

#thing1/thing2/thing3/

#thing1/thing3/thing5/thing7/thing9/
```

The first thing I do is remove the actual hash

```
window.location.hash.substring(1);
```

Now I have something like:

```
thing1/thing2/thing3/
```

I want to get thing1, thing2 and thing3 and store them in a format I can loop over, maybe like this:

```
var urlStrings = ["thing1", "thing2", "thing3"];
```

I hope someone is able to help me solve this problem, any help/advice is much appreciated.

Comment: `.Split()` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.split` function, like this

```
var urlStrings = window.location.hash.substring(1).split("/");
```

Answer (score 0):

Split them like this:

```
var str = 'thing1/thing2/thing3';
str.split('/');
```

And you can use indexes to get them:

```
str[1];//thing2
```